# Authentication failure in Hadoop

Tags: authentication, hadoop

I have already installed Hadoop and already added user as hduser to group, but I have forgotten the password of the user i.e. hduser. When running `su hduser` from the terminal I get the result:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

How can I reset the the user password in Hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo passwd hduser` will let you change the password for this user